# Materialized table from a topic in ksqlDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to create a materialized table from a topic. I am creating and producing data into the topic as follows:

```
kafka-topics.sh create --bootstrap-server <ip:port> --partitions 2 --topic my-users-topic

kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server <ip:port> --topic my-users-topic
>{"id":1,"usertimestamp":1651818648,"gender":"nobody","region_id":"nowhere"}

kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <ip:port> --topic my-users-topic --from-beginning --property print.headers=true --property print.partition=true
Partition:1 NO_HEADERS  {"id":1,"usertimestamp":1651818648,"gender":"nobody","region_id":"nowhere"}
```

After this, I created the materialized table as follows:

```
ksql> CREATE SOURCE TABLE testusers (
     id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
     usertimestamp BIGINT,
     gender VARCHAR,
     region_id VARCHAR
   ) WITH (
     KAFKA_TOPIC = 'my-users-topic', 
     VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
   );

Message                                
----------------------------------------
 Created query with ID CST_TESTUSERS_57 
----------------------------------------
```

When I am querying the above table, I see no data

```
ksql> select * from testusers;
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ID                                              |USERTIMESTAMP                                   |GENDER                                          |REGION_ID                                       |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
Query terminated
```

The persistent query is in running state but the data is not getting updated. Is there something obvious that I am missing here.

Edit: When I am trying to create the materialized table from a stream with latest offset, it works as explained in the docs.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you run something like `SET auto.offset.reset = earliest` before you created the table? Or did you try to produce data after the table was made?

Comment: Yes I tried both. No luck.